# RequestFactoryEditorDriver#getPaths() usage?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwt-editors

HI: Below code is from RequestFactoryEditorDriver:

```
 /**
   * Returns a new array containing the request paths.
   * 
   * @return an array of Strings
   */
  String[] getPaths();
```

My question is,

1. When and in what place to use this method, there is no place to set paths to the RequestFactoryEditorDriver, is the paths generated when creating the driver? if so, what's the rule of "generating paths"?
2. I think the client should provide the paths themselves, such as:

   factory.find( proxyId ).with( myPaths).fire(...)

other than from RequestFactoryEditorDriver#getPaths(), if the paths get from 1 is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths are computed from the editor hierarchy. The list basically includes all the properties being edited that are not simple values (primitives, strings, dates, etc.)

If you have the following:

```java
TextBox name;
DateBox dateOfBirth;

@Path("manager.name")
Label managerName;

AddressEditor address;
```

`getPaths` would return `"manager", "address"`.

The idea is that you can pass the value directly to `with()` and you'll retrieve all the objects needed by the editor. If you add or remove a subeditor down the hierarchy, you don't have to change your request code, the `getPaths` value will be different and contain what's needed by the editor.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the reply,  when i flush a driver immediately after edit, i always found the driver is changed(which should not because i didn't modify anything in the UI), How to trace problems like this?
editorDriver.edit( getProxy(), createSaveRequest( getProxy() ) );
editorDriver.flush();

Comment: Could it be http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5952 ? or maybe http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6713 ? (still wondering how it relates to `getPaths` though ;-) )

Comment: HI Thomas: your links are quite helpful, however still i am not sure what field cause the problem, is use below code to dump proxy before and after flush(),  they are exactly the same! AutoBeanCodex.encode( AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean( entityProxy ) ).getPayload();    How could i debug this problem? using eclipse seems it can not debug into the diff() method.

Comment: Compare `RequestContext#isChanged()` with `EditorDriver#isDirty()`, update to 2.5.0-rc1 to see if it's still an issue (only one of the above 2 issues is fixed), look at what goes over the wire when you `fire` the request context, or use a `ProxyStore` instead of `AutoBeanCodex`. (but you should be able to step into `diff`)

Comment: By using `EditorDriver#isDirty()` instead of `RequestContext#isChanged()`, my app seems work well till now. I also used a flag to indicate the proxy is newly created or re-entered. Thank you very much for the help. this problem really bothered me much these days.